# emacsclient starts a new instance instead of contacting the server started by systemd

Tags: emacsclient, systemd-integration

1. Log into Gnome
2. **emacs-server** is started by **systemd**, using the default configuration of my distribution (Fedora 36):

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
# The location of the SSH auth socket varies by distribution, and some
# set it from PAM, so don't override by default.
# Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

3. Start an **emacs-client** frame using the Gnome shell.

At this point I can use `magit` and pull and push remote commits without typing my ssh key passphrase.

4. Start an **emacs** frame (not a client) using the Gnome shell.

At this point I also can use my ssh key without typing the passphrase.

5. Start an **emacs-client** frame using the Gnome shell.

I try to pull from my remote, **emacs** asks me for my ssh key passphrase.

I'm puzzled. I really would like to be able to continue using my ssh keys without typing the passphrase on subsequent **emacs-client** frames. This glitch becomes really annoying when I'm using emacs across multiple physical screens.

Comment: Is `(emacs-pid)` returning the same value in both client frames?

Comment: @phils no, I get different values. How do I fix that? I'm starting `emacs` with a desktop laucher using the command `emacsclient -c -a ""`

Comment: So that's the issue -- two independent Emacs instances/servers, only one of which knows about your SSH config.  You'll have to check what "emacs-server is started by systemd" is actually doing.  (I can't guess what that would be, sorry.)

Comment: @phils I added the configuration above.

Comment: Oh, I can just create a new frame instead of starting a client! `Ctrl-x 5 2` or `make-frame` or `make-frame-on-monitor`... As usual, there's a command for it, but finding which one is the trick.

Comment: Sure.  It doesn't solve the actual issue, though.  I'd still want to find out why `emacsclient -c` isn't seeing the same server that your systemd thing is running.  After all, you can close all your visible frames for a server, so being able to reconnect is important (IMO).

Comment: @phils Happy to continue to bugtrack, but I don’t know where to look next. Can you provide guidance?

Comment: I would start by checking `C-h v server-socket-dir` in its server vs the one you started yourself.  They're presumably different.  Establishing what the differences are might point you in the right direction.  (If they're *not* different then perhaps `C-h v server-name` is, but nothing you've shown suggests that to me.)

Comment: Running `C-h v server-socket-dir` in the second frame (created via the Gnome shortcut) opens a buffer with the results on the first frame. So no problem there. Same if I run `emacsclient -c` from the terminal. So I can't reproduce the problem anymore. Win?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that **emacsd** wasn't aware of `$XAUTHORITY`, which controls authentication within **X**. I now included it within the environment variables **emacsd** is aware of using **exec-path-from-shell**.

```
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :straight t
  :config
  (dolist (var '("PATH" "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" "SSH_AGENT_PID" "GPG_AGENT_INFO"
                 "LANG" "LC_CTYPE" "NIX_SSL_CERT_FILE" "NIX_PATH" "XAUTHORITY"))
    (add-to-list 'exec-path-from-shell-variables var))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

If you're wondering, I include `$PATH` so that **lsp** can find executables.